# Cutting Last Bar chart in HorizontalBarChart

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I am getting issue in `Charts` graph library.

[Charts Library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

I am using `HorizontalBarChartView`

Getting below issue:

[image]

**Below is my code for Charts setting :**

```
- (void)setupBarChartForPinData {

    switch (_selectedLegend) {
        case kAppGraphAllLegend:
            _barPinChartHeightConstarins.constant = (self.mutArrPinList.count*2)*15;
            break;
        case kAppGraphLegend1:
            _barPinChartHeightConstarins.constant = (self.mutArrPinList.count*15);
            break;
        case kAppGraphLegend2:
            _barPinChartHeightConstarins.constant = self.mutArrPinList.count*15;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         // Called on parent view
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         _scrView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrView.contentSize.width,_containerView.frame.size.height + 8 );
                     }];


    _barChartPins.delegate = self;
    _barChartPins.drawBarShadowEnabled = NO;
    //_barChartPins.minOffset = 0;
    _barChartPins.dragEnabled = YES;
    _barChartPins.dragDecelerationEnabled = YES;
    _barChartPins.chartDescription.enabled = NO;
    _barChartPins.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = YES;

    _barChartPins.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0;

    ChartXAxis *xAxis = _barChartPins.xAxis;
    xAxis.labelPosition = XAxisLabelPositionBottom;
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = YES;
    xAxis.labelCount = self.mutArrPinList.count;
    xAxis.valueFormatter = self;
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = YES;
    xAxis.labelFont = kAPPCiscoSansTTNormal(10.0);
    xAxis.labelTextColor = kAppPrimaryHeading;


    ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _barChartPins.leftAxis;
    leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;

    _barChartPins.leftAxis.enabled = NO;
    _barChartPins.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;

    _barChartPins.rightAxis.enabled = NO;
    _barChartPins.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
    _barChartPins.legend.enabled = NO;

    [self setPinGraphData];
}
```

**Setting Data:**

```
- (void)setPinGraphData
{

    NSMutableArray *arrVals1 = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *arrVals2 = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.mutArrPinList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            [arrVals1 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                                initWithX:idx
                                yValues:@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[obj[@"outstanding"] doubleValue]]]]];
            [arrVals2 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                                initWithX:idx
                                yValues:@[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[obj[@"incoming"] doubleValue]]]]];

    }];

    BarChartDataSet *set1 = nil;
    BarChartDataSet *set2 = nil;
    if (_barChartPins.data.dataSetCount > 0)
    {
        set1 = (BarChartDataSet *)_barChartPins.data.dataSets[0];
        set1.values = arrVals1;

        if (_barChartPins.data.dataSetCount > 1) {
            set2 = (BarChartDataSet *)_barChartPins.data.dataSets[1];
            set2.values = arrVals2;
        }


        [_barChartPins.data notifyDataChanged];
        [_barChartPins notifyDataSetChanged];
    }
    else
    {
        set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:arrVals1];

        set2 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:arrVals2];

        NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        switch (_selectedLegend) {
            case kAppGraphAllLegend:{
                [set1 setColor:kAppLegend1GraphColor];
                [set2 setColor:kAppLegend2GraphColor];

                [dataSets addObject:set1];
                [dataSets addObject:set2];
                break;
            }
            case kAppGraphLegend1:{
                [set1 setColor:kAppLegend1GraphColor];
                [dataSets addObject:set1];
                break;
            }
            case kAppGraphLegend2:{
                [set2 setColor:kAppLegend2GraphColor];
                [dataSets addObject:set2];
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }


        BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];

        if (_selectedLegend == kAppGraphAllLegend) {

            //Setup fro GroupBars
            double groupSpace = 0.3;
            double barSpace = 0.05;
            double barWidth = 0.3;
            // (0.3 + 0.05) * 2 + 0.3 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
            // (baSpace + barWidth) * dataSet count + groupSpace = 1.0

            int groupCount = arrVals1.count;
            int startYear = 0;

            data.barWidth = barWidth;
            _barChartPins.xAxis.axisMinimum = startYear;

            [data groupBarsFromX:0 groupSpace:groupSpace barSpace:barSpace];

            double groupWidth = [data groupWidthWithGroupSpace:groupSpace barSpace:barSpace];
            _barChartPins.xAxis.axisMaximum = startYear + groupWidth * groupCount;
            _barChartPins.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = YES;

        }else{
            _barChartPins.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = NO;
        }


        [data setDrawValues:YES];
        [data setValueTextColor:kAppPrimaryHeading];
        [data setValueFont:kAPPCiscoSansTTNormal(8.0f)];
        _barChartPins.data = data;
    }
}
```

I am using both group bars and single bar, In group bars its working fine but in single bar its cutting last bars.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is "HorizontalBarChartView"? Please mention the library you use, and maybe tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Eiko Please read question properly I have already mention that I am using Charts library and also tag Charts for this question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It wasn't apparent to me that the library is called "Charts" - and it shows what a poor name that is; but of course not your fault. :) BTW, the charts tag is a general one and not limited to that particular library. Providing the link is the way to go, thank you.

Comment: I am als9 facing same issue let me.know if you found any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution for above issue.

As i said I am doing  conditional code for Enable group chart that is creating problem b'cus I am changing axis minimum and maximum manually as per group space  and bar width.

```
data.barWidth = barWidth;
_barChartPins.xAxis.axisMinimum = startYear;
_barChartPins.xAxis.axisMaximum = startYear + groupWidth * groupCount;
```

Due to above code while I remove group and go for Normal one its agin taking my custom max & min `xAxis` value so for that we have to reset `xAxis` Min & max like below.

```
_barChartPins.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = NO;
if ([_barChartPins.xAxis isAxisMinCustom]) {
  [_barChartPins.xAxis resetCustomAxisMin];
}
if ([_barChartPins.xAxis isAxisMaxCustom]) {
  [_barChartPins.xAxis resetCustomAxisMax];
}
data.barWidth = 0.5f;
```

This will solve my problem for extra space on top & bar cutting at bottom.

Hope this will helps others for same issue.

Thanks.